# Cant Export to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

I have a sql compact database connected to my website called `Sort.sdf`, with a table called "sort". I need to export all the records from the table to an XML file, but I keep getting the following error and cannot find a solution:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while 
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not 
found or was not accessible. 

Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named 
Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to 
SQL Server)
```

I have used the same connection to successfully insert data into the database, so I don't think there is a problem there.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|Sort.sdf");
conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Sort", conn.ConnectionString);
da.Fill(ds); //error on this line

ds.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\output.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: You need a SqlCeDataAdapter . `conn` is never used here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|Sort.sdf");
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from  sort", cnn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

StreamWriter xmldoc=new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Testdo.xml"), false); 
ds.WriteXml(xmldoc);
xmldoc.Close();
```

Comment: what is the problem you have with that code? see your application storage area, there it will be generated